# ZF2 Form, how to add a custom validator

Tags: php, zend-framework2

How can i add a custom validator to a ZF2 form?
I would like to add a custom validator to a zf2 form element or the form class itself to validate multiple elements against each other.

```
use Zend\Form\Form;    
class MyForm extends Form {

    public function init()
    {
        // Add some elements
        $this->add(
            $this->getFormFactory()->create(...);
        }

        // How can i add a custom validator here to the form or element?
    }

}
```

**My Current Solution**

is very simpe but effective, the form class or the fieldset has has to implement the interface *Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface*

Now i can add something like this:

```
use Zend\Form\Form;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface;
use \PayrollAccountingValidator;
class MyForm extends Form implements InputFilterProviderInterface {

    public function init()
    {
        $this->getFormFactory()->create(
            array(
                    'name' => 'salary',
                    'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Number',
                    'attributes' => array(
                            'min' => 0,
                            'step' => 1
                    ),
                    'options' => array(
                            'label' => _('Salary?')
                    )
            ));
    }

    public function getInputFilterSpecification ()
    {
        return array(
                'salary' => array(
                        'validators' => array(
                                new PayrollAccountingValidator($this)
                        )
                )
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13476164/zend-framework-2-custom-validators-for-forms) might help you. Or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13933755/zend-framework-2-custom-form-validation), or even in the official documentation where they discuss this [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.validator.writing-validators.html). Please search first.

Answer (score 3):

What I would do:

- Create the form
- Create a input filter with a dependency of the validator
- Add the validator to the field in the filter
- Set the filter to the form in a factory.

**Example**

Form:

Here we merely add the elements to the form.

```
class SomeForm extends Form {

   public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct('someform');

        $this->add(array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Textarea',
            'name' => 'somelement',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Message',
            )
        ));
    }
}
```

Filter:

Here we create the filter for the releveant elements in the above form. We add the validator passed in at instantiation when creating the input filter:

```
namespace SomeModule\Form;

use Zend\InputFilter\Factory as InputFactory;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterAwareInterface;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterInterface;

class SomeFormFilter implements InputFilterAwareInterface {

    protected $customValidator;

    protected $inputFilter;

    public function __construct($customValidator) {
        $this->customValidator = $customValidator;
    }

    public function setInputFilter(InputFilterInterface $inputFilter) {
        throw new \Exception("Not used");
    }

    public function getInputFilter() {
        if (!$this->inputFilter) {

            $inputFilter = new InputFilter();
            $factory = new InputFactory();

            $inputFilter->add(
                $factory->createInput(
                    array(
                        'name' => 'somelement',
                        'required' => true,
                        'filters' => array(array(
                                'name' => 'StringTrim')
                        ),
                        'validators' => array(
                            $this->customValidator
                        ),
                    )
                )
            );

            $this->inputFilter = $inputFilter;
        }

        return $this->inputFilter;
    }
}
```

Module.php

We can now create a factory for the form to manage the filters validator dependency and apply the filter to the form:

```
public function getServiceConfig() {
     return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'someForm' => function($sm) {
                $form = new SomeForm();
                $validator = new CustomValidator() // or $validator = $sm->get('CustomValidator');
                $formFilter = new SomeFormFilter($validator);
                $form->setInputFilter($formFilter->getInputFilter());
                return $form;
            },
        ),
    );
}
```

You will obviosly need to make sure you use the correct namespaces in your Module.php or provide the FQCN's.

Now you can get this form, fully configured in you controller with one line of code:

`$form = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('SomeForm');`

If you have any more questions feel free to ask.